# Is it grammatically correct to say “Will be off the work at...!”

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
“Will be off the work at...!” Something like:

> “(Dave) will be off the work at (5 o’clock)”

Does this sentence need a subject?

Comment: It's not a syntactically valid sentence. What is it supposed to mean? There *are* contexts where you could say something like *He **will be off the work at** 5 o'clock*, but that would be very rare compared to ***...will be off work...*** (without the article, which would normally convey a slightly different meaning anyway).

Comment: Something like: “(Dave) will be off the work at (5 o’clock)?”

Comment: oic - just lose the article, then. In many contexts, people also don't bother with the word ***work*** - *I'm meeting Dave later this afternoon. He'll be off at 5, so I'll catch him as he leaves the office.*

Comment: So “(what time you) will be off the work at....?” is worng in “all” context? It does not make any sense!?

Comment: From your point of view as an *early* learner, you might as well just assume you should ***never*** include the article before ***work*** in contexts like *I start work at 9, I finish work at 5, I go to work on a bus, I left work early yesterday,...* It does occur in rather different contexts, such as *This book is the work of the Devil, The builder said the work will take several weeks,....* but you can learn those later.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the definite article. The sentence should be:

> Dave will be off work at 5 o'clock.

Only use "the work" when referring to some specific task or assignment, not when referring to someone's occupation in general. As such, "off the work" meaning "no longer working" will almost never be correct.